# How to get max score in php multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, max

I have below array

```
$usersAttemptsInfo = [
    "1" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2],
    "2" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4],
    "3" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "4" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3],
    "5" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "6" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2],
    "7" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3]
];
```

I want to find out who is highest mark, suppose two person taking taking same marks i need that two values.

> expected out put

```
$expected = [
"3" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
"5" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5]
];
```

Here `5` is maximum score, so i am expecting this answer.

> ```
> my code
> ```

```
    $higiestScore = max(array_column($usersAttemptsInfo, 'totalCorrectQuestion'));
```

but it's returning only one score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `max()` function will only return only one value and there's no problem with the result. Instead, you can try to filter the array with the `totalCorrectQuestion`  to get the other array with the same value aftere you have done you max function.

Update:
You can try this

```
<?php
$usersAttemptsInfo = [
    "1" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2],
    "2" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4],
    "3" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "4" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3],
    "5" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "6" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2],
    "7" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3]
];


$highestscore = max(array_column($usersAttemptsInfo, 'totalCorrectQuestion'));

$results = array_filter($usersAttemptsInfo, 
               function ($item) {
                                global $highestscore;
                                if($item["totalCorrectQuestion"] == $highestscore) return $item;
                              });

var_dump($results);

?>
```

Comment: Can you please post your answer